# The access violation of the .NET program crashes, why are all "????"

Tags: c#, .net, windbg

My program crashed, and I used `!analyze -v` to observe the crash information as follows:

```
0:044> !analyze -v
CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=000001659f8a6d88 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000001651ea6f680 rdi=000001659f8a6ef0
rip=00007fffba779159 rsp=0000001d4e67e080 rbp=0000001d4e67e6f0
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000001 r13=0000001d4e67ef40
r14=000001669eb81260 r15=000001649ed30978
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69:
00007fff`ba779159 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
Resetting default scope

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  (.exr -1)
ExceptionAddress: 00007fff41750e46
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000001
   Parameter[1]: 000000000000003c
Attempt to write to address 000000000000003c

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

WRITE_ADDRESS:  000000000000003c 

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - 0x%p            0x%p                    %s

EXCEPTION_CODE_STR:  80004003

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000001

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  000000000000003c

FAULTING_THREAD:  ffffffff

STACK_TEXT:  
0000001d`4e67e6c0 00007fff`41750e46 MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x26
0000001d`4e67e700 00007fff`41750d71 MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x31
0000001d`4e67e740 00007fff`41750d1b MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x1b
0000001d`4e67e770 00007fff`41750cba MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x5a
0000001d`4e67e7b0 00007fff`4174ff8c MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x2c
0000001d`4e67e800 00007fff`4174f4e1 MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x541
0000001d`4e67e8a0 00007fff`41754e85 MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x85
0000001d`4e67e900 00007fff`42678a26 MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x66
0000001d`4e67e940 00007fff`42678910 MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x90
0000001d`4e67e9a0 00007fff`42678844 MySql.Data.dll!Unknown+0x24
0000001d`4e67e9e0 00007fff`422183e2 System_Transactions!System.Transactions.DurableEnlistmentAborting.EnterState+0x182
0000001d`4e67ea80 00007fff`421c88a9 System_Transactions!System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.EnterState+0xd9
0000001d`4e67eaf0 00007fff`422180f1 System_Transactions!System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Timeout+0xe1
0000001d`4e67eb60 00007fff`42217f88 System_Transactions!System.Transactions.Bucket.TimeoutTransactions+0x88
0000001d`4e67ebc0 00007fff`42217ea3 System_Transactions!System.Transactions.BucketSet.TimeoutTransactions+0x13
0000001d`4e67ebf0 00007fff`4216ff0a System_Transactions!System.Transactions.TransactionTable.ThreadTimer+0x2da
0000001d`4e67ec50 00007fff`99305ab3 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal+0x163
0000001d`4e67ed20 00007fff`99305944 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x14
0000001d`4e67ed50 00007fff`9933b0ba mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback+0xba
0000001d`4e67edb0 00007fff`9933aeb7 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire+0x87
0000001d`4e67ee20 00007fff`992f5b05 mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers+0x75
```

I found it was a classic access violation exception, I found no method and type name under the mysql module。

Use `!dumpmodule` to view the metadata of mysql.data.dll and find that the content is "????"

```
0:044> !dumpmodule 00007fff3ca0a0a0
Name:       C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\39e7c3dd\c0e7da90\assembly\dl3\2ef6683b\00af0014_1ddbd301\MySql.Data.dll
Attributes: PEFile 
Assembly:   00000168ae59c190
LoaderHeap:              0000000000000000
TypeDefToMethodTableMap: 00007fff3ca744d8
TypeRefToMethodTableMap: 00007fff3ca74b38
MethodDefToDescMap:      00007fff3ca756f0
FieldDefToDescMap:       00007fff3ca7a1a0
MemberRefToDescMap:      0000000000000000
FileReferencesMap:       00007fff3ca7d0d8
AssemblyReferencesMap:   00007fff3ca7d0e0
MetaData start address:  00000168b01b5328 (233004 bytes)
0:044> dp 00000168b01b5328 
00000168`b01b5328  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000168`b01b5338  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000168`b01b5348  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000168`b01b5358  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000168`b01b5368  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000168`b01b5378  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000168`b01b5388  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
00000168`b01b5398  ????????`???????? ????????`????????
0:044> !address 00000168b01b5328

Usage:                  <unknown>
Base Address:           00000168`b0192000
End Address:            00000168`b01f5000
Region Size:            00000000`00063000 ( 396.000 kB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000002          PAGE_READONLY
Type:                   01000000          MEM_IMAGE
Allocation Base:        00000168`b0190000
Allocation Protect:     00000080          PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY


Content source: 0 (invalid), length: 331ec
```

What does this mean? Is mysql.data.dll corrupted?

This is the unmanaged stack at the time of the exception.

```
0:044> .ecxr; k
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=000001659f8a6d88 rcx=0000000000000000
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000001651ea6f680 rdi=000001659f8a6ef0
rip=00007fffba779159 rsp=0000001d4e67e080 rbp=0000001d4e67e6f0
 r8=0000000000000000  r9=0000000000000000 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000001 r13=0000001d4e67ef40
r14=000001669eb81260 r15=000001649ed30978
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69:
00007fff`ba779159 0f1f440000      nop     dword ptr [rax+rax]
  *** Stack trace for last set context - .thread/.cxr resets it
 # Child-SP          RetAddr               Call Site
00 0000001d`4e67e080 00007fff`9a3a11e9     KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x69
01 0000001d`4e67e160 00007fff`9a3a121b     clr!NakedThrowHelper2+0x9
02 0000001d`4e67e190 00007fff`9a3a1225     clr!NakedThrowHelper_RspAligned+0x1e
03 0000001d`4e67e6b8 00007fff`41750e46     clr!NakedThrowHelper_FixRsp+0x5
04 0000001d`4e67e6c0 00007fff`41750d71     0x00007fff`41750e46
05 0000001d`4e67e700 00007fff`41750d1b     0x00007fff`41750d71
06 0000001d`4e67e740 00007fff`41750cba     0x00007fff`41750d1b
07 0000001d`4e67e770 00007fff`4174ff8c     0x00007fff`41750cba
08 0000001d`4e67e7b0 00007fff`4174f4e1     0x00007fff`4174ff8c
09 0000001d`4e67e800 00007fff`41754e85     0x00007fff`4174f4e1
0a 0000001d`4e67e8a0 00007fff`42678a26     0x00007fff`41754e85
0b 0000001d`4e67e900 00007fff`42678910     0x00007fff`42678a26
0c 0000001d`4e67e940 00007fff`42678844     0x00007fff`42678910
0d 0000001d`4e67e9a0 00007fff`422183e2     0x00007fff`42678844
0e 0000001d`4e67e9e0 00007fff`421c88a9     System_Transactions!System.Transactions.DurableEnlistmentAborting.EnterState+0x182
0f 0000001d`4e67ea80 00007fff`422180f1     System_Transactions!System.Transactions.TransactionStateAborted.EnterState+0xd9
10 0000001d`4e67eaf0 00007fff`42217f88     System_Transactions!System.Transactions.EnlistableStates.Timeout+0xe1
11 0000001d`4e67eb60 00007fff`42217ea3     System_Transactions!System.Transactions.Bucket.TimeoutTransactions+0x88
12 0000001d`4e67ebc0 00007fff`4216ff0a     System_Transactions!System.Transactions.BucketSet.TimeoutTransactions+0x13
13 0000001d`4e67ebf0 00007fff`99305ab3     System_Transactions!System.Transactions.TransactionTable.ThreadTimer+0x2da
14 0000001d`4e67ec50 00007fff`99305944     mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal+0x163 [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 954] 
15 0000001d`4e67ed20 00007fff`9933b0ba     mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run+0x14 [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs @ 902] 
16 0000001d`4e67ed50 00007fff`9933aeb7     mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback+0xba [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\timer.cs @ 713] 
17 0000001d`4e67edb0 00007fff`992f5b05     mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire+0x87 [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\timer.cs @ 670] 
18 0000001d`4e67ee20 00007fff`9a3a6a93     mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers+0x75 [f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\timer.cs @ 425] 
19 0000001d`4e67eea0 00007fff`9a3a6948     clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+0x83
1a 0000001d`4e67eee0 00007fff`9a3a720d     clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x4e
1b 0000001d`4e67ef20 00007fff`9a3a9a04     clr!MethodDescCallSite::CallTargetWorker+0xf8
1c 0000001d`4e67f020 00007fff`9a3a79d1     clr!AppDomainTimerCallback_Worker+0x34
1d 0000001d`4e67f110 00007fff`9a3a7940     clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x39
1e 0000001d`4e67f150 00007fff`9a3a787d     clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
1f 0000001d`4e67f250 00007fff`9a3aa784     clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75
20 0000001d`4e67f2e0 00007fff`9a3aa886     clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInCorrectAD+0x15
21 0000001d`4e67f310 00007fff`9a3aa7db     clr!Thread::DoADCallBack+0x278
22 0000001d`4e67f4d0 00007fff`9a3a7940     clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+0x2e4b
23 0000001d`4e67f510 00007fff`9a3a787d     clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+0x6c
24 0000001d`4e67f610 00007fff`9a3a7a0f     clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+0x75
25 0000001d`4e67f6a0 00007fff`9a3a99a6     clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+0x2f
26 0000001d`4e67f700 00007fff`9a3a9906     clr!AppDomainTimerCallback+0x7c
27 0000001d`4e67f760 00007fff`9a3a944f     clr!ThreadpoolMgr::AsyncTimerCallbackCompletion+0x7e
28 0000001d`4e67f7b0 00007fff`9a3a804c     clr!UnManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0x1bc
29 0000001d`4e67f850 00007fff`9a3a7df5     clr!ThreadpoolMgr::ExecuteWorkRequest+0x64
2a 0000001d`4e67f880 00007fff`9a3ac1cf     clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0xf5
2b 0000001d`4e67f920 00007fff`bb697974     clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x86
2c 0000001d`4e67f9e0 00007fff`be2ba271     kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14
2d 0000001d`4e67fa10 00000000`00000000     ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: An "Access Violation" means that something went wrong in unmanaged code. As a .NET developer, the correct way to fix this is to create a [mcve], submit it to the developer of the unmanaged library and let them fix it.

Comment: Is there a problem to simply debug your code or provoking the problem that you went this way?

Comment: Possibility a) DLLs are not necessarily loaded into memory completely and you're trying to view a part of the DLL that hasn't been loaded. b) the metadata start address is incorrect for whatever reason and it points to memory which is not available.

Comment: Why are you interested in the meta data of MySql.Data.dll ? I have never needed the metadata of a DLL to debug a crash. You have the full path of the DLL, so you can look up that information outside of WinDbg.

Comment: "Is mysql.data.dll corrupted?" Maybe. Save a copy, reinstall/repair Mysql and compare the DLLs for differences

Comment: @ThomasWeller    Thank you for your reply, the trigger scenario of this problem is: In the case of automatic recycling of IIS, the program will crash occasionally. This is the crashed dump file. It is found that the metadata of mysq.data.dll is damaged, which may be because of `mysql.data .dll` appears in an intermediate state during the process of unloading or loading into the process. I checked the `mysql.data.dll` in the folder path and there is no problem. Maybe it is the problem of IIS itself.

Comment: 1) Stack traces with full symbolic information would possibly yield a better understanding of what's going wrong; 2) memory not present in a dump doesn't imply there is a problem with this memory, it just might not be present in the dump: you should configure the automatic "dump on crash" to generate a full dump with as much information as possible in the `CustomDumpFlags` (see [collecting user mode dumps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wer/collecting-user-mode-dumps)).

Comment: my bad, just saw that  .NET apps are not supported by WER ?; if you can find the equivalent for .NET apps, it would worth a shot.

Comment: Does PrintException show any managed exceptions on the stack?